# Passing ViewModel between ActionResults without using TempData

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Right now what I am doing is using TempData on passing my ViewModel to another Action.

But my colleague advised me that I should not use TempData because they have experience issues with TempData before to our LoadBalancers.

Here's part of my controller so that you can see what I want to do. 
How can I achieve the same process without using TempData or Session. 
Please advise, Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    MyViewModel viewModel;

    if (TempData["viewModel"] != null)
    {
        viewModel = (MyViewModel)TempData["viewModel"];
        //code for getting dropdownlist to show to view

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    viewModel = new RequestViewModel();
    //code for getting dropdownlist to show to view

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //collect data, but not yet save to database

        TempData["viewModel"] = viewModel;

        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    }

    //code to get errors, and dropdownlist items to re-show to view
    return View(viewModel);
}

public ActionResult Confirm()
{
    if (TempData["viewModel"] != null)
    {
        var viewModel = (MyViewModel)TempData["viewModel"];

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Confirm(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //save data to database if confirmed

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

--EDIT--

I also tried to pass viewModel to redirectToAction via parameter but my viewModel didn't repopulate after the redirect. Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //collect data, but not yet save to database

        return RedirectToAction("Confirm", viewModel);
    }

    //code to get errors, and dropdownlist items to re-show to view
    return View(viewModel);
}

public ActionResult Confirm(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        //some code

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Review")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ConfirmPost(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //save data to database if confirmed

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the check method for page load doesn't do anything but return the view, could you not use

```
return View("Check", viewmodel);
```

Comment: Nope, Check View is where the user check if all the inputs are correct. Either user will cancel or continue with the submit button on Check View

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding is check a new view?

Comment: Yes, Check is a new view wherein users can validate his/her inputs then decide if he/she will continue.

Comment: yes I saw that, I tried that earlier, but the viewmodel doesn't repopulate after the request.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't appear on the check view or that it doesn't submit after?

Comment: it didn't repopulate after getting to Confirm Get view. Please see my edit on the post. Thanks Ben! :)

Comment: what does the check method do, or does it just return the view?

Comment: sorry, there's no Check(), it's Confirm View, confirm view will just show a table of inputs to confirm if user want to proceed.

Comment: Ok check that answer :) does that help

Comment: yap that works! BUT, post buttons (save or cancel) triggers the post action of Create() instead of Review post action.

Comment: Ok so I've solved the questions issue?  :) we can move into a chat to solve this other issue if that's cool :) don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115534/discussion-between-ben-jones-and-jomsk1e).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your situation is due to the fact that TempData uses a server session to store its contents, which is problematic in a multi-server environment. You could implement your own tempdata provider in order to make it use a cookie instead. Some possible solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28355862/1942895

https://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider

http://vijayt.com/Post/Custom-TempDataProvider-for-Azure